# DCS RGU-366 Oven will no longer heat

Tags: electrical, gas, appliances, oven

**I have:**

DCS RGU 366-N oven

**What happened:**

Wife ran oven with the door slightly open, heating up all control knobs.

**Symptoms:**

- Oven will no longer heat up.
- Ring-light for oven knob no longer lights up.

**I checked:**

- Gas supply: OK
- Electrical Power: OK
- Stove burners work, including Stove control knobs and lights.
- When turning up oven temperature, the relais clicks ON and OFF as I set it higher or lower.

What should I be replacing for this oven, to repair it? There was a schematic on the back of the oven, as depicted below.

[image: schematic]

Specification Label:

[image: specifications]

UPDATE:

I removed the front panel, and then removed the over temperature control knob, depicted below:

[image: temperature control for oven]

I used the Ohm Meter to check that the relais indeed closes and opens as I set the temperature. I am going to assume that unit is still good.

I also have this part, which I suspect is the "Stalled Fan Thermostat?"

[image: SFT]

Comment: UPDATE: It was indeed the L85C part, a thermostat that sits on the control panel, behind the turn knobs.

Answer (score 1):

### I'd check that and the High Temp Cutout as well

Assuming the "ring light" is either the Oven Heating or the Oven Ready light (or both), I'd check both the Stalled Fan cutout and the High Temp cutout (which will look similar to the cutout you have) to make sure that they have continuity.  If they're both working, though, I'd send for a new oven thermostat at that point.